# How do I get a list of all Cayenne-managed entity classes?

Tags: java, apache-cayenne

I'm using Apache Cayenne as an ORM in my web application and I want to get a list of all entity classes that are managed by Cayenne (for example [Person.class,Account.class,...]).

My goal is to register these classes in an Object<->PrimaryKey Converter for easy parameter handling.

How would I do that?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm using Cayenne 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [examples](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cayenne/examples/trunk/) and the [Javadocs](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc30/api/index.html) - every aspect of Cayenne is accessible from the API. E.g. you could:

1. Get a reference the your Datamap by e.g. following the path: [DataContext](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc30/api/org/apache/cayenne/access/DataContext.html) -> [EntityResolver](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc30/api/org/apache/cayenne/map/EntityResolver.html) -> [DataMap](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc30/api/org/apache/cayenne/map/DataMap.html)
2. Iterate on all DBEntities or better on all ObjEntities (if they're already mapped - but you can map at runtime dynamically too) - see the methods of DataMap for doing all these operations, such as: DataMap#getObjEntities() or DataMap#getDbEntities() and the others.
3. For all those properties, there are not only getters but also setters if you want to change something at runtime is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Cayenne class has methods for mapping an object to a primary key [objectforPK](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc/api/org/apache/cayenne/Cayenne.html#objectForPK(org.apache.cayenne.ObjectContext,%20java.lang.Class,%20int)) . That might do what you're after.